# import python packages from another directory into a Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where a user uploads some images and I have some image processing routines which I write and they reside in a completely different folder in my hard drive (on the same machine).

Now, I plan to use something like celery to process these images. So, the idea would be that as soon as the files get uploaded, I can start some celery task which would process these images.

Now, I was wondering how I can change my Django settings so that these image processing routines are available from within my Django project? So, my image processing project has the following structure:

```
ip
 --- calibration
 --- io
 --- report
 --- utils
```

So from my django project, I hope to be able to do something like:

```
from io import *
```

and be able to use the classes defined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must append the folder to your python path using `sys.path.append()` then import using the module name as normal

[Credit](http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html)